# Generate n random numbers Summed upto cell value Vba code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hi I'm trying to generate n random numbers in Vba code so that their sum must be different in each time:

one time sum must be 1000
one time sum must be 1500...and so on
the sum in the code is called (items)

the problem is the array I didn't want to generate the random numbers for fixed rows, I need to generate randomly one time 10 rows for one columns..one time 15 rows for 1 columns...
How can I fix that?

```
Sub randomality()
Dim ary(1 To 10) As Double, zum As Double
Dim i As Long
Randomize
zum = 0
Dim destination_order_unit As String
Dim items As Variant

 Number_required = Range("K2").Value
 destination_order_unit = Range("L5").Value
  Range(destination_order_unit).Select
 items = InputBox("All units ")
 Range("J2").Value = items

  For i = 1 To 10
    ary(i) = Rnd
    zum = zum + ary(i)
Next i

For i = 1 To 10
    ary(i) = ary(i) / zum
Next i

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For i = 1 To 10
        Cells(i, "D").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(items * ary(i), 0)
    Next i
    Cells(10, "D").Value = items - .Sum(Range("D1:D9"))
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is more along the lines of how to insert an array that goes vertically? The random number issue is throwing me off and I'm having a hard time following, but this is how you could create a set of 10 random numbers that sum to 20. You could re-engineer this if you're trying to just ensure they are not the same at the end of the loop by saying <> to.

```
Sub BuildRandoms()
    Const minNumber As Long = 0
    Const MaxNumber As Long = 5
    Const finalSum As Long = 20


    Dim ary(1 To 10) As Long, i As Long

    Do
        For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            ary(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(minNumber, MaxNumber)
        Next i

    Loop Until Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ary) = finalSum

    'resized the range you're trying to paste values
    Range("D10").Resize(UBound(ary), 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ary)

End Sub
```

Comment: if the final sum is not fixed, for each user ID in column A has a final sum in column E how can I generate sth like this using this code?